# jQuery menu hover with prepend/append not working correctly in different browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover, jquery-append

My script works almost perfectly in FF, Opera and IE. Chrome and Safari shows a slightly different behaviour.

Hover seems to be working fine. But when I hover on the "selected" li, it appends an additional div. This additional div overlaps on the existing div and does not give a smooth hover effect. Chrome and Safari behaves a bit differently to this additional div. When I hover on selected li in Chrome and Safari, they remove the div from the selected li and add it before the first. I know where this additional div is coming from in the jQuery script but I'm unable to resolve this issue.

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="first"><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
    <li class="last selected"><a href="#">List 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

​

CSS:

```
ul.nav li div.menu-hover { 
  width:10px; height:10px;
  background-color:black; position:absolute; left:40px; display:none;
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$("ul.nav > li").hover(

function() {
    $(this).prepend("<div class='menu-hover'></div>");
    $("ul.nav > li div.menu-hover").fadeIn("slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).find("div:last").remove();
});

$("ul.nav > li.selected").prepend("<div class='menu-hover'></div>");
$("ul.nav > li.selected > div.menu-hover").fadeIn("slow");​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current menu-hover (the current selected menu) should be fixed, you can test this version of code. It keep the current menu-hover untouched and manage hover() on other menu.
It is the basic behaviour of a menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul.nav > li").hover(function() {

        // Do not append menu-hover on selected li
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        return;

        // Append menu-hover on non-selected li
        $(this).prepend("<div class='menu-hover'></div>");
        $("ul.nav > li div.menu-hover").fadeIn("slow");

    }, function() {

        // Do not remove menu-hover on selected li
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
            return;

        // Remove menu-hover on non-selected li
        $(this).find("div:last").remove();
    });

    // Manually set the current menu-hover
    $("ul.nav > li.selected").prepend("<div class='menu-hover'></div>");
    $("ul.nav > li.selected > div.menu-hover").fadeIn("slow");

});
```

Comment: No still not working. This takes it back to the initial situation - works in FF but not in Chrome.

Comment: Actually your solution works. It was my CSS that was playing up. I had to spend hours to figure this out. Anyway thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The hover(function1, function2) jQuery function take 2 parameters which are 2 callbacks functions, called respectively when the mouseOver event is fired, and when the mouseOut is fired.

In your code, just after your hover definition, you add manually the selected menu, but the hover function does not manage previous manually add, so you should add this specific case in your code. (When you enter with your mouse on the menu for the first time, there is no mouseOut event.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul.nav > li").hover(function() {
        // previously remove all potential menu-hover
        $(".menu-hover").remove();

        // prepend the menu at the good place and show it smoothly
        $(this).prepend("<div class='menu-hover'></div>");
        $("ul.nav > li div.menu-hover").fadeIn("slow");
    }, function() {
        // remove the menu on mouse Out
        $(this).find("div:last").remove();
    });

    // Manually select the first menu
    $("ul.nav > li.selected").prepend("<div class='menu-hover'></div>");
    $("ul.nav > li.selected > div.menu-hover").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: I see your point in adding $(".menu-hover").remove(); but it's still not working perfectly when I try it in different browsers. What I'm ideally after is when hovered, it should not remove the .menu-hover div.